# Deprecated Features Error When Compiling Gradle for Minecraft Forge

Tags: java, gradle, minecraft-forge

I am working on developing a Minecraft mod, and I am running into issues compiling the `gradlew` file provided by Minecraft Forge. I have attempted to install multiple versions of Gradle, then uninstall all of them, using [SDKMAN!](https://sdkman.io).

In order to build the Gradle project, I set the working directory to the Forge folder, then executed the following command: `./gradlew genEclipseRuns`.

After about 8 seconds, the following error appears:

```
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 5.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/4.9/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 8s
```

Running `gradle -version` shows that I am using version 2.7. This issue occurs when trying to compile Gradle files from multiple recent versions of Forge. How can I resolve this issue so that the project compiles correctly even though it, "uses Deprecated Gradle features"?

Comment: Note that `gradle` and `gradlew` are not the same thing. The latter uses the "[Gradle Wrapper](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html)", which will download (if needed) and use the Gradle version the project uses (appears to be 4.9). Presumably, the version used by the project should work without issue. I've never personally had a Gradle build _fail_ because of a deprecation _warning_ — are you sure that's the actual cause of failure? Also, the [Forge Documentation](https://mcforge.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gettingstarted/) doesn't seem to mention a `genEclipseRuns` task.

Comment: I’m not exactly sure that is what causes the error. Though, it is what terminal claimed was the error. The documentation I’m referring to is the `README.txt` that comes with the Mod Development Kit, though I have deferred to the online documentation, which still results in the same issue. I have, in the past, had an error where it claimed it was the Java version, but then I reverted to Java 1.8 and this new error came about. I will note that gradlew and gradle are different and put some research into the gradle wrapper having this error.

Comment: Is that the full terminal output?

Comment: No. I can post the full console output. I just have to run it again.

Comment: Ok, reading over the console output, I was able to fix the error, apparently none of the commands I was using were apart of the gradlew version. My apologies for pulling your leg about this.